# Custom Button in django

Tags: django

I am trying to create custom Button in Django Admin

**admin.py**

```
class HeroAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
change_list_template="hellogym/hellogymapp/templates/change_list.html"
```

**change_list.html**

```
{% extends 'admin/change_list.html' %}
{% block object-tools %}
    <div>
        <form action="immortal/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Make Immortal</button>
        </form>
        <form action="mortal/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <button type="submit">Make Mortal</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br />
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

I have created superuser Admin and I want a custom button inside it

Comment: I don't have any idea to how to do it

Comment: Please provide your error info.